# What type of animation should I use in this case? Flash, frame by frame or other?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, adobe-flash, adobe-after-effects

Good day!
I'm making a game where I need a sprite animation. It's a pretty simple animation but I need to decide what kind of specialist I need to hire to make the animation for me.

[image]

This is the sample of the object that I want to animate. I need the core of the object to shoot beams and the shell of the object to be like a blobby-blob, changing its shape constantly, morphing new appendages.

The artist that draw me this sample could make a frame by frame animation. But I wander - may be there is a better way to do that? May be there are some applications that does exactly what I need without all the unnecessary job? I would be thankful for advice!

Comment: Well maybe. But you should let your artist quoute a price and ask a countor offer from somebody else. Animation is allways tedious, either itd tedious to set up or tedious to animate

Comment: it depends on what platform this game is going to be developed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate 2 things here.

1) The process

2) The output

I mention this becouse flash could be considered an output format or a tool to make a frame by frame animation.

The same with the concept of sprites. That could be an output method or a process.

In my opinion you could use a morph, defining some key frames and making an automated in between images automathic.

Yes you could do that in flash using vectors. Also there are some free software to make that on photos (bitmaps) https://www.google.com/search?q=free+morphing+software (always take proper care when installing free software)

After that, you define your output format. This could be animaged gif, video or a series of still images (probably png), then you could asamble them in Photoshop to prepare a single png file for sprite animation on CSS, depending of your needs.